# PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR_NEED_VALID_FUNDING_INSTRUMENT

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal Android SDK with PHP for payment testing. I have tested with both Credit Card (Sandbox) and Paypal login (Sandbox). Credit card has no issue, payment went thru successful. This error is not code, the code is well tested and has been working quite well before. Payment with Paypal is having issue. Below is screenshot.

[image]

[image]

This is the error details:

```
10-05 18:06:32.084  23691-31439/com.test.paypalclient E/paypal.sdk﹕ request failure with http statusCode:422,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unprocessable Entity
10-05 18:06:32.094  23691-31439/com.test.paypalclient E/paypal.sdk﹕ request failed with server response:{"name":"PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR_NEED_VALID_FUNDING_INSTRUMENT","debug_id":"d43cc8cf90433","message":"session is NON_PAYABLE","information_link":"https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/supplemental_errors.md"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into your test buyer account in Sandbox and add funding sources to it. Log in to your Sandbox account and check the funding tab under the buyer profile.

Comment: Of course, I have funding source. I mentioned Credit Card payment is working fine, Credit Card is from Funding tab. Meaning funding source is there.